# Is Spartacus 2.0 compatible with IE11 and Edge?

Tags: angular8, spartacus-storefront

is Spartacus 2.0 compatible with IE11 and Edge?
or can we have a list of compatible browsers with versions ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Based on official documentation:**

On the desktop, Spartacus supports Chrome with automated tests, and in general, Spartacus supports evergreen browsers. By default, Spartacus does not support IE11 because IE11 is missing certain modern browser features, such as support for CSS variables.

Spartacus supports browsers on mobile and tablet platforms as follows:

- On iOS-based devices, Spartacus is tested with Safari and Chrome. Although other browsers are not tested, Spartacus should work with any iOS browser, because all iOS browsers use the Webkit-based iOS browser engine.
- On Android-based devices, Spartacus is tested with Chrome, which is based on Chromium and the Blink layout engine. Any Android browser that uses the same engine will likely work with Spartacus. Other browsers using different browser engines are not tested, but those browsers that use Webkit should work as well.

You can find out more details here - https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/spartacus-faq/#which-browsers-does-spartacus-support.

**But in practice:**

You can support IE by self if you will not use `@spartacus/styles` library, cuz Angular fully supports IE 11.

Comment: We've updated the docs and created a separate docs page on this topic, see https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/browser-support/.